# How can I use a WinForms PropertyGrid to edit a list of strings?

Tags: c#, string, winforms, propertygrid

In my application I have a property grid to allow users to change settings.  This works fine for strings and other value properties, but what I need now is a list of strings that can be edited by users.

The problem is that if I have `MyPropertyGrid.SelectedObject = new { Test = new List<string>() };` in my code and the user attempts to edit the `Test` property, when they click on the Add button, the following error occurs:

```
 Constructor on type 'System.String' not found
```

This makes sense as strings are immutable.  However, I still need some way to store multiple strings (or string-like data) in a property grid.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Try this,

   MyPropertyGrid.SelectedObjec = Test //it'll return string list  

on button click set the string list in the Test property....

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean to try, as it looks like your code got eaten up by the commenting format.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Yes, you can [specify an `System.ComponentModel.Editor` attribute on your list of strings, with `StringCollectionEditor` as the editor](http://mastersact.blogspot.com/2007/06/string-collection-editor-for-property.html).  You need to add a reference to System.Design.Dll to your project, in order for this to compile.

Example, suppose your object is like this:

```
[DefaultProperty("Name")]
public class CustomObject
{
    [Description("Name of the thing")]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [Description("Whether activated or not")]
    public bool Activated { get; set; }

    [Description("Rank of the thing")]
    public int Rank { get; set; }

    [Description("whether to persist the settings...")]
    public bool Ephemeral { get; set; }

    [Description("extra free-form attributes on this thing.")]
    [Editor(@"System.Windows.Forms.Design.StringCollectionEditor," +
        "System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
       typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(CsvConverter))]
    public List<String> ExtraStuff
    {
        get
        {
            if (_attributes == null)
                _attributes = new List<String>();
            return _attributes;
        }
    }
    private List<String> _attributes;
}
```

The property grid for that looks like this:

[image]

Click on the `...` and you get:

[image]

If you don't like the builtin collection editor, [you can implement your own custom collection editor](http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/winform/8766/String-Collection-Editor).

My example shows the use of a TypeConverter attribute.  If you *don't do that*, then the list displays in the prop grid as "(Collection)".  The TypeConverter [gets it to display as something intelligent](http://windowsclient.net/blogs/faqs/archive/2006/05/26/how-do-i-change-the-collection-string-in-a-uitypeeditor-for-a-collection.aspx).  For example, to display a short string representation of the collection in the property grid, like this:

[image]

...the TypeConverter is like this:

```
public class CsvConverter : TypeConverter
{
    // Overrides the ConvertTo method of TypeConverter.
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
       CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        List<String> v = value as List<String>;
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
        {
            return String.Join(",", v.ToArray()); 
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

You don't need a setter on the `List<String>`, because the collection editor doesn't set that property, it merely adds or removes entries to the property.  So just provide the getter.

Comment: Awesome, the first method works like a charm (The string collection editor should work fine for my needs).  Much appreciated :)

Comment: Excellent answer !

Answer (score 11):

If you just need a string container just use: `BindingList<string>` instead of `list<string>`

**The editor is created automatically.**

Also, "casting" back and forth to `List<T>` is easy. 
From List to BindingList just use the `bList = BindingList(orignalList)` constructor (if you get read only error - insert the list one by one). and to get the list you can use the `.ToList()` extension method.

Answer (score 3):

Property declaration misses one important attribute:
`[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]`

Without it designer does not serialize collection data.

Comment: It works without the attribute if you use a binding list, ie, BindingList<string>