# I am getting error like "constructor on type 'system.string' cannot found" for a User Control in C#?

Tags: c#, user-controls, autocomplete, textbox, stringcollection

For a usercontrol TextBox i am creating properties like `AutoCompleteCustomSource`, `AutoCompleteMode` and `AutoCompleteSource`:

```
public virtual AutoCompleteStringCollection AutoCompleteCustomSource 
{ 
    get { return txtLocl.AutoCompleteCustomSource; } 
    set { txtLocl.AutoCompleteCustomSource = value; } 
}

public virtual AutoCompleteMode AutoCompleteMode 
{ 
    get { return txtLocl.AutoCompleteMode; } 
    set { txtLocl.AutoCompleteMode = value; } 
}

public virtual AutoCompleteSource AutoCompleteSource 
{ 
    get { return txtLocl.AutoCompleteSource; } 
    set {txtLocl.AutoCompleteSource=value;} 
}
```

I am creating like that but i am getting error like this for `AutoCompleteCustomSource` string collection. i show you the error 
[image]

and what i want is i show in the below figure

[image]

Comment: i try it befor posting this one but it i totally different i think so..,

Comment: Please look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307006/how-can-i-use-a-winforms-propertygrid-to-edit-a-list-of-strings

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, I hope it will work:

```
public string[] AutoCompleteCustomSource
{
    get
    {
        List<string> lStringList = new List<string>();
        foreach (string lval in this.mEkaTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource)
        {
            lStringList.Add(lval);
        }
        return lStringList.ToArray();
    }
    set
    {
        txtLocl.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(value);
    }
}
```