# StringCollection editor does not store the values entered by user

Tags: c#, .net, windows, listbox, stringcollection

I have implemented StringCollection editor in my custom control and below is the code :

```
[Description("extra free-form attributes on this thing.")]
[Editor(@"System.Windows.Forms.Design.StringCollectionEditor," +
    "System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
   typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
public System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection Items
{
   get
   {
      if (items == null)
         items = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();

      return  this.items;
   }
}

public System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection items;
```

This works fine but every time i enter some value in the collection and re-open it.. values are lost i.e. it does not store the values.

Is there anything missing to store the value of user entered strings or do i need to implement custom StringCollection so that user entered string values persist in the String Editor.

I even refered to below given link.. but still issue exists :
[How can I use a WinForms PropertyGrid to edit a list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307006/how-can-i-use-a-winforms-propertygrid-to-edit-a-list-of-strings)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to apply [DesignerSerializationVisibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibilityattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute to `DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content`. Without that all changes to the complex objects(other than primitives, strings, etc) will be lost.

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
[Description("extra free-form attributes on this thing.")]
[Editor(@"System.Windows.Forms.Design.StringCollectionEditor," +
    "System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
   typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
public System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection Items
{
   get
   {
      if (items == null)
         items = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();

      return  this.items;
   }
}
```

Comment: as suggested .. i tried the above given option.. but still issue exists.

Comment: @user1291401 Just tested, that works fine for me. Which version of VisualStudio you use? Try cleaning the solution and rebuild it. Then check, that may help...

Comment: @ Sriram Sakthivel - VS 2012 and even tried cleaning, rebuilding the solution .. still issue exists. And even it is not getting reflected in the listbox also.

Comment: @user1291401 What do you mean by *and even it is not getting reflected in the listbox also*? What listbox? Post a complete sample which demonstrates the problem. Otherwise hard to help, because it works for me.

Comment: i have implemented custom control.. similar to ListBox. Now i'm using the StringCollection Editor so that user can enter strings in editor and it should be stored/reflected in my custom control. But every time i click StringCollection Editor it is always empty even though last time i enter few string values in it. Hence i mentioned it  -- it is not getting reflected in the listbox.

Comment: Where does your control inherits from? Do you mind positing the custom control code? Only relevant code to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You might also try creating the list in your constructor.  That along with the string collection editor and DesignerSerializationVisibility attributes  works for me.

```
[Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.StringCollectionEditor, System.Design", "System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor, System.Drawing")]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public List<string> TestList { get; set; }

public ListTest()
{
    TestList = new List<string>();
}
```