# Use a custom editor in a PropertyGrid for a type I cannot modify

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propertygrid

In my application I have an object which's properties I want to edit using a PropertyGrid. For most of the properties this works fine. Now this object contains a property of type `List<string>`. When editing this property I get an error because `string` doesn't have a suitable constructor.

Basically this is the same situation as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6307006/3959259).

Unfortunately I can't use the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6308677/3959259) from there because I can't modify the code of my object, so applying the `Editor` attribute to the property is not an option. Is there an other way to use a custom editor here?

Comment: `PropertyGrid` uses type descriptors, it doesn't rely on reflection. So you don't need to add the `Editor` to the property itself. It's enough to provide a suitable type descriptor for the class. You can apply the `Editor` to the property at run-time, by providing a new type descriptor for the class at run-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot change the code of your class, you can register a new type descriptor for your class at run-time to provide custom type description.

Using [`AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.associatedmetadatatypetypedescriptionprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) you can create a type descriptor provider for your class that uses a metadata class to provide type description. Then you can register the provider using [`TypeDescriptor.AddProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1x0wz2y6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

**Example**

Let's suppose the class which you cannot change its code is like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        List = new List<string>();
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> List { get; set; }
}
```

The to solve the problem, you should define another class like that with the same properties and decorate those properties with attributes which you like, including the editor and converter attributes:

```
public class MyClassMetadata
{
    [DisplayName("Name Property")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Editor(@"System.Windows.Forms.Design.StringCollectionEditor," +
        "System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, " + 
        "PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
        typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
    public List<string> List { get; set; }
}
```

Then before showing the original class, register a new type descriptor provider for the original class which returns the metadata using the metadata class which we created:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var provider = new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(MyClass),
        typeof(MyClassMetadata));
    TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(provider, typeof(MyClass));
    this.propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = new MyClass();
}
```

I suppose you already have the `CsvConverter` from the [first link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6307006/3959259):

```
public class CsvConverter : TypeConverter
{
    // Overrides the ConvertTo method of TypeConverter.
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
       CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        List<String> v = value as List<String>;
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
        {
            return String.Join(",", v.ToArray()); 
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can see a step by step example here in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46099675/3110834).